# How can I get Firebase Auth to display an error?

Tags: swift, firebase-authentication

I want to set up email/password authentication with firebase, and have this written which is similar to the documentation. I have only one registered email that I'm testing with, and when I attempt to sign in with that everything works well. But when I enter another email/password, the completion block does not execute.

```swift
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { [weak self] (user, error) in
            guard let strongSelf = self else {
                return
            }
            if let error = error {
                let errorAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
                errorAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
                strongSelf.present(errorAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                return
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I fixed it. I had a performSegue line right outside of the completion, when it should have been inside, after the guard and if let statement.